# Sprite with <img> tag

Tags: html, css, sprite, css-sprites

If I understand correctly the idea of sprites, it's meant to reduce HTTP requests.
It make sense when I use `<span>`, `<i>` or `<div>`, since I can give several element one class and give that class `background-image`. That way the browser requests the image only once. But how is that work with img tag? The src attribute cannot be empty, so if I set three images like that:

```
<img id="first" src="img-sprite.png" alt="" />
<img id="second" src="img-sprite.png" alt="" />
<img id="third" src="img-sprite.png" alt="" />
```

Basically I have three different requests here. Three requests that requesting for the same image, but still three.
Can someone please enlighten me.

Thanks!

Comment: The browser is smart enough to make only one request and re-use the same image.

Comment: I wish there was an option to see why people downvote a question, I would really like to know what's wrong with my question. Anyway, thanks @Juhana

Answer (score 0):

Image sprites are used in numerous web apps where multiple images are used. Rather than include each image as a separate image file, it is much more memory and bandwidth-friendly to send them as a single image, so the number of HTTP requests is reduced.

[Implementing image sprites in CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Implementing_image_sprites_in_CSS)